# Groovy JDK 11 BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'FileUpload.groovy'

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to compile below code Gralde 4.9, Groovy-2.5.2 and JDK11, it giving this error, same code compiles in JDK 8.

```
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils
import picocli.CommandLine
import picocli.CommandLine.Command
import picocli.CommandLine.Option

@Command(name = "FileUpload", version = "File Upload 0.1", mixinStandardHelpOptions = true, description = "@|bold Groovy|@ @|underline picocli|@ example")

@Slf4j
class FileUpload implements Runnable {
    @Option(names = ["-u", "--url"], paramLabel = "<URL>", description = "URL to upload")
    String url

    @Option(names = ["-f", "--filename"], paramLabel = "<FILENAME>", description = "filename to upload")
    String filename

    @Option(names = ["-d", "--debug"], description = "Enable Debug")
    String debug

    void run() {
        if (debug) {
            System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");
            System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime", "true");
            System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.wire", "DEBUG");
            System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.impl.conn", "DEBUG");
            System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.impl.client", "DEBUG");
            System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.client", "DEBUG");
            System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http", "DEBUG");
        }

        if (!filename || !new File(filename).exists()) {
            log.info( "File name argument missing, or File not found $filename")
            usage()
            return
        }

        if (!url) {
            log.info( "URL required")
            usage()
            return
        }

        upload(url, filename)
    }

    def static void main(args) {
        CommandLine.run(new FileUpload(), args)
    }

    def static usage(){
        println '''
            Usage: FileUpload -u http://webserver/home/upload -f c1.csv
        '''
    }

    public static void upload(url, filename) throws Exception {
        if (!new File(filename).exists()) {
            System.out.println("File path not given");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        try {
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            File f = new File(filename)
            FileBody bin = new FileBody(f);
            StringBody comment = new StringBody("A binary file of some kind", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);

            HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                    .addPart("filename", bin)
                    .addPart("filename1", new StringBody(f.getName()))
                    .addPart("comment", comment)
                    .build();

            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            log.info("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            try {
                log.info("----------------------------------------");
                log.info(response.getStatusLine().toString());
                println(response.getStatusLine());
                log.info("----------------------------------------");
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                if (resEntity != null) {
                    log.info("Response content length: " + resEntity.getContentLength());
                }
                EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }

}
```

**Error message**

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:273)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:258)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'FileUpload.groovy' null
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:179)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.GroovyCompilerFactory$DaemonSideCompiler.execute(GroovyCompilerFactory.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.GroovyCompilerFactory$DaemonSideCompiler.execute(GroovyCompilerFactory.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerCallable.call(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerCallable.call(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:76)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:42)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.execute(WorkerDaemonServer.java:46)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.execute(WorkerDaemonServer.java:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:101)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassVisitor.visitNestMemberExperimental(ClassVisitor.java:248)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:651)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:391)
```

I have github project here : https://github.com/sfgroups/FileUpload

Comment: Kudos for using picocli!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have encountered https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8727.

Comment: Thanks I will wait for 2.5.3 release and test this one

Comment: Did groovy 2.5.3 solve this for you? I'm seeing it in groovy 2.5.4 with gradle 5.2.1, but the problem disappears when I back off from JDK 11 to JDK 8.